# PHP IPv4 and IPv6 function to store in a database

Tags: php, mysql, ipv6, ipv4

I want to store IP addresses along with user registrations, posts, uploads etc. Previous sites I've made I've always used `ip2long/long2ip` and stored it as an `UNSIGNED INT` as IPv4 was my only concern. So I'd run the IP address through `ip2long`, store it, and when I retrieve it, use `long2ip`. But now I want to make sure it's a bit more future proof and tackle both IPv4 and IPv6.

This is a function I've come up with so far to handle both IPv4 and IPv6:

```
function ipCheck()
{
    // Get IP Address
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) // Shared client
        {
            $ipAddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) // Proxy address
        {
            $ipAddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else
        {
            $ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // User viewing
        }

    // Over IP for testing
        /*
            IP Examples for testing

            IPv4:   64.233.160.0
            IPv6:   2607:f0d0:1002:51::4
            IPv6:   2607:f0d0:1002:0051:0000:0000:0000:0004
        */

        $ipAddress = '2607:f0d0:1002:0051:0000:0000:0000:0004'; // Comment out this line for actual IP

    // Validate IP
        if (filter_var($ipAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
        {
            if (strpos($ipAddress, ':') !== false)
            {
                $ipType = 'IPv6';
                $ipAddressDB = inet_pton($ipAddress);
            }
            else
            {
                $ipType = 'IPv4';
                $ipAddressDB = ip2long($ipAddress);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $ipType = 'Invalid';
            $ipAddressDB = $ipAddress;
        }

    // Display results
        echo '<strong>IP Type: </strong>'.$ipType.'<br />',
             '<strong>IP Address: </strong>'.$ipAddress.'<br />',
             '<strong>DatabaseIP: </strong>'.$ipAddressDB;
}

ipCheck();
```

I personally don't have an IPv6 address so I've overridden the `$ipAddress` variable for testing purposes.

Everything works fine for IPv4 addresses, but `$ipAddressDB` for IPv6 addresses returns the value `&(diamond-with-question-mark)(diamond-with-question-mark)Q` when I use the `2607:f0d0:1002:0051:0000:0000:0000:0004` testing IP and I really have no idea why? Am I using `inet_pton` wrong? Do I have to add something to it? Is it because of the test IPv6 address?

I'd assume once I get that working, as we need to store in 2 columns, I create 2 variables for the database IP, if it's IPv4 I assign it to variable 1 and leave variable 2 blank. Then if it's IPv6, I split it, putting the first half in variable 1 and the 2nd in variable 2. Then when it comes to inserting/selecting, if the second column is empty, we can assume it's an IPv4 address?

I'm not even 100% sure if what I'm trying to do is actually doable? If not, would it be better to just take the IPv6 addresses as they are (without `inet_pton`), and just split them that way?

Comment: What do you need ip address for? The only variable you can trust is `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. Others are just rubbish.

Comment: Can I ask why are the others rubbish? (serious question)

Comment: because the sender can put literally anything there (and only `REMOTE_ADDR` is filled by a webserver from the connection info (which can be forget as well, but then the sender won't retrieve the response back))

Comment: So scrap the `ifelse` at the start of the function for `HTTP_*` and just stick with `REMOTE_ADDR`. Thanks for the advice! Any clues as to the main question? Why `inet_pton` returns such a strange value?

Comment: On a side note, it may be an issue that your `ipCheck()` function allows 'spoofing' the IP address by simply adding an `X-Forwarded-For: myfakeip` header to the request.

Comment: @Joe: "and I really have no idea why" --- and what would you expect to see? PS: use `var_dump()` not `echo` to check the data

Comment: @zerkms Well I'd assumed something other than diamonds with question marks in them if I'm honest, it wasn't my first thought of a possible returned value... Since `ip2long/long2ip` returns a value and it's based on the whole human readable/storage format, it seemed like a plausible possibility that `inet_pton/inet/ntop` would do something similar.

Comment: @Joe: just use `var_dump($var)` and see

Comment: @zerkms `string(16) "&��Q"` with `var_dump()`

Comment: @Joe: now see the page source

Comment: @zerkms The source code says the same? Should it be different?

Comment: @Joe: For me it looks like `&\aðÐ\020\002\000Q\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\004`

Answer (score 1):

You're viewing the address in binary form. "&" is UTF-8 0x26, 0xf0 and 0xd0 are invalid UTF-8 (displayed as "�"), "Q" is UTF-8 0x51, and the other bytes have a null display. Encode the bytestring as hex before storing (and then you can treat IPv4 addresses exactly the same way).

Comment: Like this? `$ipAddressBin2Hex = bin2hex($ipAddress); $ipAddressDB = inet_pton($ipAddressBin2Hex);` Apologies if I've got that wrong!

Comment: As you mentioned the encoding, it got me thinking, would it be to do with what I set a `meta` tag `charset` attribute to. I usually use `<meta charset="utf-8">`, so I tested it by setting that and putting the function within the `<body>`. Then created a new page with nothing but my `ipCheck()` function and the values on either page were different. I tried the `bin2hex` function the way I wrote above and I received a `Warning: inet_pton() [function.inet-pton]: Unrecognized address`...